# Merge the [named-arguments] and [named-parameters] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

I noticed that there are separate tags for [named-arguments](/questions/tagged/named-arguments) and [named-parameters](/questions/tagged/named-parameters) on Stack Overflow, so I'm suggesting that these tags should be merged, since they appear to be completely synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

That was 9 questions to retag, from [named-arguments](/questions/tagged/named-arguments) to [named-parameters](/questions/tagged/named-parameters).

[named-arguments](/questions/tagged/named-arguments) will be deleted tomorrow.